# How to uninstall files added after installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, registry, windows-installer

When I use an MSI to install an application it registers all files that must be remove. But if in a patch I need to add new files, those won't be removed on uninstall. How to make this to happen?

One way I thought was to modify the MSI to remove the folder even if there are files present. But this will only affect new installations, not existing ones.

I also tried to alter the Windows Registry, to include this new file in the list of files to be removed. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes made by a patch should also be removed if you created the patch correctly. How do you create your patch? Do you follow the [patching rules from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367850.aspx)?